# Which operations preserve digit precision?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision

Imagine I had to use numbers with a 600 precision digits. Do all mathematical operations, like `+`,`-`,`Times` *et cetera* preserve precision digits?

Comment: Does that include things like Sin, Exp, and other mathematical expressions?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes, Exp, ^, /, etc. The most usual ones

Comment: It depends on the magnitude of the numbers and what you mean by "preserve". For example, adding ``1.`600`` to ``10.`600^601`` obviously loses all of the 600 digits of precision of the 1.

Comment: I would say the answer is yes to what I would guess is your question:  All the mathematical functions keep track of precision given arbitrary-precision numbers for input.  "Preserve" is a confusing term, since in subtracting like-sized numbers, you lose a significant amount of precision, according to how precision is supposed to be calculated (which is what happens in *Mathematica*).